# Websocket. Python. Забивается сокет

Tags: python, linux, websocket, администрирование

Здаврутвсйте,

Вот настроенный инстанс **websocket-client**:

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.128.116:3000", on_message=on_message, on_open=lambda a: on_open(ws))
```

Т.е. в сокет, после открытия передаю коллбэк `on_open(ws)`

Этот коллбэк слушает нажатие клавиш и отправляет в сокет. **Если клавиша зажата**, то между отправками задержка 0.1 сек.

Проблема:

Если держать клавишу нажатой **продолжительное время**, то уходит много пакетов и соединение "висит", т.е. если зажать другую клавишу, она отправится через некоторое время (чем дольше была зажата клавиша - тем дольше ждать).
Если перезапустить скрипт, то отправляется сразу.

P.S. Понимаю, что скорее всего связано с тем, что websocket это TCP и пакеты должны проходить проверку доставки и целостности.
Для понимания: это забивается именно сокет между клиентом и сервером?

Comment: клиент с той стороны должен вычитывать сообщения. Если никто не вычитывает, то как раз и будет описанная выше ситуация.

Comment: Сервер (клиент на "той стороне") - это ардуино. Отрабатывает в принципе быстро на однократное нажатие. Т.е вы считаете, что не хватает тактовой частоты у ардуино?

Comment: ну может быть такое - отправляется команда "включить лампочку на 1 секунду". И код выглядит где то так - `digitalWrite(M1, HIGH); sleep(1); digitalWrite(M1, LOW);` и тут никакая частота не поможет.

Comment: У меня нет блокирующих операций типа delay, все на millis (типа асинхронка ардуиновская)))

Comment: я привел как пример. я не знаю, как там выглядит код.